# Avoiding global vars means forced to declare same var in different functions?

Tags: javascript

As a beginner I've been told to avoid global variables cause
names can collide specially as a project grows. But I'm also told
coding is about efficiency and you should not do things twice.
Avoiding global variables leaves me declaring the same variable
in different functions which feels like the wrong thing to do.
What is the way to go? Thank you, peace and love.

```
//GLOBAL SPACE - no variables here, wanna be a good boy

function one(){
    var box = document.getElementsById('box');
    //DO SOMETHING WITH BOX
}

function two(){
    var box = document.getElementsById('box');
    //DO SOMETHING ELSE WITH BOX

}
```

Comment: you can minimize collisions if you learn about namespacing patterns in javascript: http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/ This can help you avoid repeatedly caching the same variable and keep the code contained in groups.

Comment: In your particular case you can wrap your code in an anonimous function and define (and initialize, if reasonable) your common variables inside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on how `one` and `two` are being accessed. You could always close over the box variable like this though:

```
var one,two;
(function(){
    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    one = function(){
        //use box
    };
    two = function(){
        //use box
    };
})()
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the best customer service in the world.
I understand now that there's no one magic trick but a few different
approaches and work arounds. In my case an anonymous function should go a pretty long way.

Answer (score 1):

redeclare your funcitons to take an argument

```
function one(box){
    //DO SOMETHING WITH BOX
}
```

That also has the advantage of moving the location of the box to just one place. Either a declaration or it's own function. Which again means that if you change how to locate the box element you won't have to change it in all methods that use it but only at one place.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript relies heavily on [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). The functions in the global namespace are closures too. Either use the OOP approach (about OOP [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))) or (as already noted in the comments) the [Module](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) pattern. The holy grail of programming is abstraction (unless you consider zeros and ones more elegant), and encapsulation by OOP is one of the major approaches. For instance:

```
var my_object = {
    box: document.getElementsById('box'),
    one: function() { }, // manipulate this.box
    two: function() { }, // manipulate this.box
};
```